# How to restore non-synced Exchange Notes on Ventura?

Tags: time-machine, notes.app, exchange

I am running macOS Ventura 13.4.1 (c) (22F770820d) on my work laptop. I have enabled my work Exchange account and am syncing Calendars, Notes, and Reminders.

While troubleshooting a sync problem with Apple's Calendar, I removed this account from "Internet Accounts" and then re-added it. Shortly after that, I discovered that a large number of my Notes for this account were missing. Not all of them, just some folders (e.g., one called "1:1s"). I want to restore them and I have recent Time Machine backups. However, I have no idea what files need to be restored to get these notes back.

I have tried copying the Notes folder from both `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes` and `~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/Outlook/Outlook 15 Profiles/Main Profile/Data/Notes` with no success. Note, I only tried copying one of these at a time and then restoring the original contents.